# GCM message not received

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have been trying to implement GCM for quite some time ... but I'm stuck ... I have posted the code and the necessary details below. Here is the manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="mypackage.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <permission
        android:name="mypackage.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launch"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".screens.WebActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".service.RegistrationIntentService" />
        <service
            android:name="mypackage.service.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name=".service.GcmMessageHandler"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="mypackage" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

other related class files

**GcmMessageHandler:**

```
extends GcmListenerService { 
String message;
public static final int MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION_ID = 435345;

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    message = data.getString("message");

    createNotification(from, message);
}

private void createNotification(String from, String message) {

    Context context = getBaseContext();
    NotificationCompat.Builder mbuilder = new NotificationCompat
            .Builder(context).setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launch)
            .setContentTitle(from)
            .setContentText(message);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION_ID, mbuilder.build());
}
```

**MyInstanceIDListenerService**

```
extends InstanceIDListenerService {

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {

        Intent tokenrefreshIntent = new Intent(this,RegistrationIntentService.class);
        startService(tokenrefreshIntent);
    }
}
```

**RegistrationIntentService:**

```
extends IntentService {

    private static final String PREFS_TOKEN_KEY = "my_token_key";
    private static final String QuickstartPreferences = "QuickstartPreferences";
    private static String User_EmailId;

    String senderId;
    String token;

    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
    NetworkOperations networkOperations;

    public RegistrationIntentService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public RegistrationIntentService() {
        super(PREFS_TOKEN_KEY);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        //        initializeClasses();
        // make call to the instance api//
        InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
        senderId = getResources().getString(R.string.google_app_id);

        //request token that will be used by the server to send the notification//
        try {
            token = instanceID.getToken(senderId, GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);

            User_EmailId = getEmiailID(getApplicationContext());
            Log.d("register_Token: ", token);

            sendRegistrationToServer(token, User_EmailId);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("error_httpproblem", e.getMessage() + " & " +     e.getLocalizedMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            sharedPrefs.edit().putBoolean(QuickstartPreferences, false).apply();
        }
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token,String email) {

        GcmTokenPost gcmTokenPost = new GcmTokenPost();
        try {
            gcmTokenPost.postToken(token,email);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("error_httpproblem", e.getMessage() + " & " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        sharedPrefs.edit().putString(PREFS_TOKEN_KEY, token);
        sharedPrefs.edit().putBoolean(QuickstartPreferences, true).apply();

        Log.d("shared_prefs", sharedPrefs.getString(PREFS_TOKEN_KEY, "default value"));
    }

    private String getEmiailID(Context context) {
        AccountManager my_accountManager = AccountManager.get(context);
        Account account = getAccount(my_accountManager);
        if (account == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return account.name;
        }
    }

    private static Account getAccount(AccountManager accountManager) {
        Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
        Account account;
        if (accounts.length > 0) {
            account = accounts[0];
        } else {
            account = null;
        }
        return account;
    }

    //    private void initializeClasses() {
    //
    //        networkOperations = new NetworkOperations();
    //    }
}
```

**what response I get from gcm**

[image: the response I get]

I can successfully send token from app to my server and from there to GCM server .. but I'm not able to get anything from the gcm server.

Comment: You server may have not sending data to GCM

Comment: Khizar hayat @, florian- do@  i think my server is able to send data .. please have a look at the image i have added in new edit

Comment: What is json you are sending from server , have you added key value pair to,"token" in json ?

Comment: have a look at the json im send to GCM server $fields = array(
"registration_ids"=>$registatoin_ids,
            "notification" =>array("text"=>"Hello from myServer! What's going?","title"=>"Hello from my Server!","color"=>"#03A9F4","icon" =>"@drawable/ic_back","sound" => "default","click_action" =>"OPEN_MAIN_ACTIVITY"),
"data"=>array("message"=>"Hello")

       );              i am reading registrationIds from db

Comment: where are you define the token for which message has to send ?

Comment: khizar @ registration_ids is the token for which im sending message   ..please correct my json code in the above comment if its wrong

Comment: i think there should be to key under notification key. see table 1 
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json

Comment: hey khizar and florian.. everything works fine .its just my network admin had some restrictions ..

Comment: florian-do@ it works on my oneplus .It doesn't word on some devices ???where could be the problem... could if be related to network or android version???

Answer (score 0):

Firstly i think you should try this tutorial from the google dev site https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start and after you successfully understood all the code you can use this link [Add Cloud Messaging to your app](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client)

And i think your problem is on your `RegistrationIntentService` class there is no subscribe token function :

This code is provide from the google-sample github

`private static final String[] TOPICS = {"global"};`

```
/**
 * Subscribe to any GCM topics of interest, as defined by the TOPICS constant.
 *
 * @param token GCM token
 * @throws IOException if unable to reach the GCM PubSub service
 */
// [START subscribe_topics]
private void subscribeTopics(String token, String id) throws IOException {
    GcmPubSub pubSub = GcmPubSub.getInstance(this);
    for (String topic : TOPICS) {
        pubSub.subscribe(token, "/topics/" + topic, null);
    }
}
// [END subscribe_topics]
```

Comment: Khizar hayat @, florian- do@  i think my server is able to send data .. please have a look at the image i have added in new edit

Comment: Try the sample server from the GCM github https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm you can run it with this command from the terminal in Android Sutdio `./gradlew run -Pmsg="test"` and i got this message on response `{"message_id":4633304339975809768}`

Comment: florian-do@ it works on my oneplus .It doesn't word on some devices ???where could be the problem... could if be related to network or android version???

Comment: @MohammedNathar do you have some error on the android monitor ? do you correctly receive the token from the GCM service ? are you using the same topic for both cellphone when you're sending the message ?

Comment: im getting the token correctly .. and im using this same code for all the phones